# How to unit test momentjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How to unit test this kind of code? I'm using JEST for this
[image]

Comment: Pass the arguments to the functions and make assertions that return value is indeed what you expect it to be.

Comment: The question isn't clear, but even if it was, please post your code inside [code blocks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) rather than images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just import the functions in my test file and then write tests passing in the dates to the functions as arguments and then expecting the values returned from these functions.

Something like this:

```
import {
  formatDate,
  startEndDate
} from "./index.js";

describe("formatDate", () => {
  it("should format date properly", () => {
    expect(formatDate(new Date("01/12/1992"))).toBe("Jan 12, 1992");
  });
  // More such tests here with different values of dates.
});

describe("startEndDate", () => {
  it("should return start and end date in proper format", () => {
    expect(startEndDate(new Date("01/12/1992"), new Date("12/12/1992"))).toBe(
      "01/12/1992 - 12/12/1992"
    );
  });
  // More such tests here with different values of start and end dates.
});
```

---

> Here's a [**Working CodeSandbox Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-kpvg9?file=/index.test.js:0-438) for your ref.

PS: Ignore the `Exceeded timeout of 5000ms for a test.` test that you see in the result. The onces(2 tests) that we've written have passed.

Comment: Thank you @SiddAjmera!!! I didn't know I can import the exact file and call it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that unit testing is required in such a case. Mocking of momentjs makes unit test rudimentary. Make an integration test.